# Apache Shiro - issue with isPermitted() method and wrong Authorizer class

Tags: apache, shiro

We have implemented a class called AuthorizerImpl that contains two objects: an AuthorizingRealm and a Subject. We have implemented an isPermitted() method which subsequently calls the isPermitted() method on the subject. Our code looks something like this:

```
// UserContext object uc is passed in here
AuthorizerImpl auth = new AuthorizerImpl(uc.getUser());
auth.isPermitted("winnebago:drive:eagle5");
```

We initially log in and authenticate a user's permissions using the above code. The first time a user logs in, it is a a "base user" so to speak. There are certain screens that are specific to certain users, so we call the above code again with a different uc.getUser() to verify the new users permissions. What I am seeing though is that the backend Shiro code is using the previous user to check the permissions, not the new user that I passed into the isPermitted() method. Each time we are calling "new AuthorizerImpl(uc.getUser())" we are creating a new Subject and AuthorizingRealm that are instance variables inside the AuthorizingRealm object. It was my impression that when I create a new AuthorizerImpl, it should use the new subject and realm that we are creating in the constructor. However, it seems that Shiro is caching the previous realm object that was used and is using that? We are using the DefaultSecurityManager. After doing some debugging, I noticed that the DefaultSecurityManager has an authorizer instance variable. It appears to be using the first authorizer object and not the new one that should be created with the new user, which leads me to believe it is is being cached. Is there a way to turn off this caching? Is this what is happening or is it something else?  The permissions are being retrieved correctly from the database if the correct user is used to check. How can I resolve this?

Thank you in advance.